# How do I make HTML5 <input type=month> to work across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

`<input type="month">`

How to make the above month picker work across all the browsers.

Comment: Check this : https://html5test.com/compare/feature/form-month-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Browsers that don't support HTML5 won't work with this. Try look at jQueryUI.